# How to snapshot and reject data in react-redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-async

This's [my first react and redux project](https://github.com/liverbool/redux-todomvc-async). I'm try to learning by doing from [main redux repo's examples](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/tree/master/examples) and i can't find an example for `todomvc async` in that repo.

Finally i've found an [excellence tutorial about redux todomvc async](http://www.sohamkamani.com/blog/2016/06/05/redux-apis/) and i'v added [this patch](https://github.com/liverbool/redux-todomvc-async/commit/52b065cf1b8a5c5f9301f49c0cce97f98b3c3751) to existing redux todomvc app.

If you see [my patch](https://github.com/liverbool/redux-todomvc-async/commit/52b065cf1b8a5c5f9301f49c0cce97f98b3c3751) you will see i'm try to add `snapshot data` when interact with remote server and use for `reject change` data back when got an error response from server.

My questions:

- What's the best practice to do for about something like i'm trying?
- How i can store `snapshot`? or
- What's best practice to `reject` change the data?

Thanks for advance.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer, see in detail http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/ImplementingUndoHistory.html